# Рандомное проигрывание libgdx

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Имеется приложение, клон flappy bird, при смерти, воспроизводится файл.
Требуется сделать так, чтобы воспроизводился не один файл, а рандомный из списка.

Код:

```
 // столкновение с землей
     if (Intersector.overlaps(fly.getCircle(), ground)) {
         if (fly.isAlive()) {

             ResourseLoader.dead.play(); // 1 трек
             ResourseLoader.dead2.play(); // 2 трек
             ResourseLoader.dead3.play(); // 3 трек

             fly.die();
             renderer.prepareTransition(255, 255, 255, 0.3f);
         }
         movHandler.stop();
         currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;
         //лучший результат
         highScore();
     }
```

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
 if (Intersector.overlaps(fly.getCircle(), ground)) {
     if (fly.isAlive()) {

        switch (new Random().nextInt(3)){
           case 0: ResourseLoader.dead.play(); // 1 трек
            break;
           case 1: ResourseLoader.dead2.play(); // 2 трек
            break;
           case 2: ResourseLoader.dead3.play(); // 3 трек
        }

        fly.die();
        renderer.prepareTransition(255, 255, 255, 0.3f);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если рандомных вариантов много, то swich станет неудобно использовать.
Тогда можно создать массив ресурсов.

Где-то он инициируется:

```
Array<Sound> sounds = new Array<Sound>();
sounds.add(dead);
sounds.add(dead2);  // и так далее, можно в цикле
```

А рандомное число будет индексом на массив:

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(fly.getCircle(), ground)) {
     if (fly.isAlive()) {

         sounds.get(MathUtils.random(0, sounds.size-1)).play();

         fly.die();
         renderer.prepareTransition(255, 255, 255, 0.3f);
     }
     movHandler.stop();
     currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;
     //лучший результат
     highScore();
 }
```